# R and roxygen2: How to document data files in inst/extdata?

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I have some data files that I want to distribute with a package I'm creating. I've placed the files in inst/extdata. How and where do I document these files using roxygen2?

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: There is nothing there I can see about how to document raw data. I've followed the R Packages book closely while developing, so of course - I've read that page :)

Comment: exactly the same as you do data in `/data` except give it a `@name raw_data1` to reference and a `NULL` value instead of `"raw_data1"`

Comment: Thank you. Do I do that in a file `R/data.R`? Is [this](http://pastebin.com/ncBsDyKv) correct? How do I reference the filename I have in `inst/extdata`?

Comment: looks fine, you can put it in any script in /r. Then you can `?raw_myDataset` to bring up that help page. I'm not sure what you mean by reference it. you can get the file path with `system.file('extdata','raw_data1.csv', package = 'your_package')`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a tag name that's used to point to the specific file in `inst/extdata` that I'm documenting? If my dataset is `inst/extdata/rollerblades.csv`, something [like this](http://pastebin.com/jfdFGmGC)?

Comment: what do you mean by point to it, what do you expect that to do? in your package it would just be a csv file, you'd have to write something to read/print or load that data if that's what you're expecting--similar behavior as `data/rollerblades.Rdata`?

Comment: Since I'm going to document the file inst/extdata/rollerblades.csv in another file, say R/data.R, I was thinking there must be some established way to refer to the data file from the documentation. Like the the tag @dataFilename I used in that example. But maybe it doesn't matter. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what's best practice, but following [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr)'s advice this is what I did:

- Created a file R/extdata.R
- Documented each file I have in inst/extdata like this:

(Ignore this line: Apparently I need some text here so that what's below turns into a code block.)

```
#' Dataset foo
#'
#' This is a dataset containing stuff.
#'
#' @name raw_datasetName
#'
#' @section datasetName.csv:
#'
#' This data is used in thisFunction().
NULL
```